# Exit the loop abruptly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's imagine the following code:

```
function DoSomethingHard(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3){
  // Do Something Hard Here
}

var i;
for(i = 0; i <= stuff.length; i++) {
  // "stuff" is an array
  DoSomethingHard(stuff[i].something1, stuff[i].something2, stuff[i].something3);
}

$( "#button_to_cancel" ).click(function() {
  //something to cancel
});
```

- Suppose the array "stuff" has 100 positions, so the for loop will run
  100 times, ie, it will do "Do Something Hard" 100 times.
- Let's also consider that "DoSomethingHard" takes about 5 seconds to run
  completely.

**My question is:** How do I manage the cancellation of "DoSomethingHard"? For example, if it has already run 50 times, how can I cancel the subsequent executions through a button? I did not succeed in my attempts and it always ends up running the whole loop ....

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is considered an anti-pattern, but you could create a global variable. var isBreak = false; for(i = 0, i < stuff.length; ++i){if(isBreak){break;}}; $('#button_to_cancel').click(function(){isBreak = true;})

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is single threaded, and a for loop executes until it is finished. I would do something like this to allow time for the cancel.

```
function DoSomethingHard(param){
 //do something
}

var i = 0;
var loopInterval = setInterval(function() {
  if (i >= stuff.length) {
    clearInterval(loopInterval);
    return;
  }
  DoSomethingHard(stuff[i]);
  i++
}, 10);

$( "#button_to_cancel" ).click(function() {
  clearInterval(loopInterval);
});
```

Comment: But what if the SetInterval run completely and DoSomethingHard() is still processing data? How could the user cancel?

Comment: The interval will execute `DoSomethingHard` for `stuff[0]`, then check for a cancel. Then execute `DoSomethingHard` for `stuff[1]`, then check for cancel. And so on. So if someone clicks cancel in the middle of one execution of `DoSomethingHard`, that call will finish before the process is cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `setInterval` to call the function and when you have a click event you can `clear the intervals`

```
var mytimeout;


var i;
for(i = 0; i <= stuff.length; i++) {
  // "stuff" is an array
  mytimeout = window.setInterval(DoSomethingHard(stuff[i].something1, stuff[i].something2, stuff[i].something3), 2000);
}

$( "#button_to_cancel" ).click(function() {
  //something to cancel
  window.clearInterval(mytimeout)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way as I see it:

```
function DoSomethingHard(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3){
//Do Something Hard Here
}

var i;
var active = true; //as of now, we want to process stuff
for(i=0;i<=stuff.length;i++){
//"stuff" is an array
if(active){
  DoSomethingHard(stuff[i].something1, stuff[i].something2, stuff[i].something3);
}else {
   active = true; //reset active in case we want to run loop again later on
   break;        // break out of loop
}
}

$( "#button_to_cancel" ).click(function() {
  active = false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily cancel it with a click on a button, unless you use recursion or iterators instead of a loop.
But you can cancel the loop inside itsself with a `break;` statement when some condition is met. For example you could write:

```
    var result;
    for(i=0;i<=stuff.length;i++){
      result = DoSomethingHard(stuff[i].something1, stuff[i].something2, stuff[i].something3);
      if (result === 'error' || i === 50) break;
    }
```

This will end the loop if result becomes the 'error' (or anything else your return from inside the function) or when i reaches 50.

Now that i think of it, it's possible with a button click, but it requires more code and is inefficient. give me a minute.
Update: I would not advice this ppttern either, but it's pretty flexible:

```
var exitCondition,
    doSomethingHard = function doSomethingHard(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3){
      // Do Something Hard Here
    },
    i,
    length = stuff.length,
    result;
for (i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
  // "stuff" is an array
  result = doSomethingHard(stuff[i].something1, stuff[i].something2, stuff[i].something3);
  if (exitCondition( result, i )) break;
}

$( "#button1_to_add" ).click(function() {
    exitCondition = function( result, index ) {
        return index === 50;
    });
});
$( "#button2_to_cancel" ).click(function() {
    exitCondition = null;
});
```

The clue here is to have an exit condition (or multiple) that you check inside the loop and have the button update this condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to note that loop is synchronous where as your function isn't. Loop won't wait for `DoSomethingHard()` to compleye before the next iteration begins.In just a few milliseconds `DoSomethingHard` has been called over a hundred times! and your loop gets over so in essence `break` is of no use here.I think no language construct can help here

So what to do?

You need to decide whether to do something or not in the function itself create a global flag and check it **inside** the function

```
function DoSomethingHard(){
  if(flag50done){
    return;
  }else{
    //do what this fn was meant for
  }
}
```

You can change value of `flag50done` with a click of a button and further actions would get stopped due to the `return`

In case `DoSomethingHard` is some 3rd party function which you cannot modify you can wrap it in another function say `runDecider`

```
   function runDecider(a,b,c){
      //add flag check here
      if(flag50done){
        return;
      }else{
       DoSomethingHard(a, b, c);
      }
   }
```

and call this in the loop

```
var result;
for(i=0;i<=stuff.length;i++){
   result = runDecider(stuff[i].something1, stuff[i].something2, stuff[i].something3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not stop a for loop from UI interaction because everything is running in a single thread and your action will execute only after loop executes completely. You can use setInterval as @jason p said.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this way:

```
function DoSomethingHard(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3){
    //Do Something Hard

    var timer = window.setInterval(function(){
    var page = $$('.page').data('page');
    console.log("The page is: "+page);
    if(page != 'preview'){
        //Cancel...

        console.log('Aborted');
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
 },1000);
}
```

That is, i changed the scope. Instead using button click, i monitered when user leave the page, so cancel it.